# Wordpress 4.* adds paragraph in shortcodes while using get_template_*

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've a big problem. I'm using several shortcodes within my template but the output is always wrong. It adds several `</p>` tags to my output, even when I add filters.

The `</p>` are set even when there are no open `<p>` tags.

Here's a part of my code. I tried everything to remove the paragraphs but no result.

I've shrinked the code for easier reading.

```
function pull_team_shortcode($atts) {
    $output = '';
    $tplgenerator = new Team_Template_Generator();
    $output .= $tplgenerator->generate_output();
    $output = trim($output);
    return "<div>" . bic_rm_wpautop($output) . "</div>";
}

add_shortcode('simple-team', 'pull_team_shortcode', 25);
```

A simple truncated class to load a template and return it back.

```
class Team_Template_Generator {
  public function generate_output() {
        ob_start();
            set_query_var('myposts', get_posts($args));
            get_template_part($this->templates . $this->template_name);
            $var = ob_get_contents();
            ob_get_clean();
            return trim($var, ".\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and a template..

```
<?php
$extra_class = get_query_var("extra_class");
$title = get_query_var("title");
$subtitle = get_query_var("subtitle");
?><section class="team">
    <div class="row<?php if ($extra_class != "") echo " " . $extra_class; ?>">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <?php
                if ($title != "" || $subtitle != "") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="border-title">
                        <?php
                        if ($title != "") {
                            echo '<h2>' . esc_html($title) . '</h2>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class='ico-border'> <i class='ico-bg flower'></i> </div>
                        <span class="tag-line">
                            <?php
                            if ($subtitle != "") {
                                echo esc_html($subtitle);
                            }
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>   
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="row pt-md">
                    <?php
//valid meta fields:
// short_bio, email, designation, web_url, telephone, location, social, profile_title, profile_linkedin, _thumbnail_id
                    foreach (get_query_var("myposts") as $post) {
                        //     echo "<pre>" . print_r($post, true) . "</pre>";
                        $meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-col-xs-12 profile">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail("medium", array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                                <ul class="text-center">
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $meta['profile_facebook'][0]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $meta['profile_twitter'][0]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $meta['profile_linkedin'][0]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <h1><?php echo trim($post->post_title); ?></h1>
                            <h2><?php echo trim($meta['profile_title'][0]); ?></h2>
                            <div><?php echo trim($post->post_content); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?></div></div></div></div></section>
```

this is a part of the output which adds `</p>` tags even if they are not open before.

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/name"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.titter.com/name"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/name"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul></div>
<h1>Christian Stimmer</h1>
<h2>Sales Leader</h2>
<div>Christian Stimmer Data</div>
</p></div>
</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Before i have included the file for adding the short code i've added in functions.php the following hack:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
```

but this didn't change anything. Any idea why it still generated `</p>` tags around?

Answer (score 0):

Just to check: have you tried removing `wpautop` and not adding it again? Do you still get the extra lines?

Comment: Yes, removing it works, but even when i add this after all widgets are loaded, it adds paragraphs again. And i cant completly remove it since other plugins (external plugins) may use it.